# “Service Unavailable” message when not logged as admin

Tags: error-message

I am junior web developer I am setting up my first website with Craft CMS. I have been getting the "Service Unavailable" error message on my site every time I try to enter not logged in as admin. I've done some searches on this StackExchange site and tried setting again the permissions for `craft/app/`, `craft/config/`, and `craft/storage/` as told in the installation docs, but didn't work. I've also tried modifying the `.htaccess` as told in other thread, but still didn't work.

Any help would be very appreciated. And forgive my ignorance since I'm very new to this CMS :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your site is enabled under Settings ➞ General ➞ System Status.

Also, check your craft.log files under `/craft/storage/runtime/logs/craft.log`.